# For my df, I'm looking to find how many women senators have a YouTube account and then create a new df with those woman w/ a YouTube account

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is my code w/ the dataset

```
function1 <- function(){
    dataset <- url("https://intro-datascience.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/role.json")
    readlines <- jsonlite::fromJSON(dataset)
    newDf <- readlines$objects$person
    finalDf <- cbind(newDf, age = df$age)
    return(finalDf)
    }
```

So far I created a function to tell me how many woman senators have YouTube accounts by subtracting 76 from the total number of male senators:

```
woman <- function(){
    a1 <- length(grep("female", df$gender))
    a2 <- length(grep("", df$youtubeid))-76
    return(sum(a1 + a2))
}
```

But for creating the new df is where I am stuck with those woman w/ a YouTube account..

Comment: Hardcoding the number of male senators (I'm guessing that's what 76 is?) defeats the purpose of writing code to calculate this. Where exactly are you stuck? Adding a column to a data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering `df` is a dataframe generated from function1. Here is an alternative within `tidyverse`

**Package**

```
library(dplyr)
```

## Solution

#### Womens with `youtubeid`

Select only `gender` == "female", **and** cases in which `youtubeid` **is not** missing `NA`. To do that, I used `filter()` from `dplyr`. So we are filtering all rows that the statement is `TRUE`. In other words, if a row has gender as "female" and has no missing for "youtubeid" then I'm keeping that row. If not, I'm dropping that row. This way, in the final dataset, I only have females with `youtubeid`.

```
women_df <- df %>%  
  filter(!is.na(youtubeid),
         gender == "female")
```

#### How many women with youtube id?

```
women_df %>% 
  nrow()
```

**output**

```
[1] 16
```

ps: I'm not sure why you are creating functions, but if you need a function for this, just wrap everything around a function (remember to include `dplyr` within the function if you want to send this to other people).

Comment: Are u able to explain how filter(!is.na(youtubeid),
         gender == "female") removes the male gender and only keep female. I see how you specified gender == "female" but how does filter(!is.na(youtubeid) know to take anything out that does not say male and is.na I thought is for NA values? and yes rookie mistake

Comment: I edited the answer to respond to your question